# Regex Match requiring @ and 

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble getting this regex to work. I need a pattern that matches a single `@` and a single `.`. Both are required.

I've tried `/(@|\.)/` but this matches either/or. I need it to fail if one is missing.

Comment: Do they need to appear in order? Can there be something between them? Could you just use `var.contains("@") && var.contains(".")`? Basically, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: And: In which language/OS do you operate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\w+@\w+\.\w+
```

( assuming you are matching email like `abc@xyz.com`. You can make it more powerful and allow digits etc. If you are not concerned with email, then you are better off just looking for '@' and '.' in your string using string functions)

Answer (score 0):

You want a String that looks like `@.`? Then you need `/^(@\.|\.@)$/`. Note: I am escaping the period because otherwise `.` stands for any single value.

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important:

```
/^(?=[^.]*\.[^.]*$)(?=[^@]*@[^@]*$).*$/
```

matches a string that contains exactly one `.` and exactly one `@`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can think of is `/@.*\.|\..*@/`. Will match any string so long as it contains at least one `@` and at least one `.` anywhere in the string.

Although probably a string function would be faster/better/more readable.